# Getting the IEnvelope from an IGeometry type using .Net Topology suite

Tags: c#, .net, gis, topology

Does anyone out there use the .Net topology suite?
I'm a bit stuck, I'm trying to get the envelope so I can validate dimensions

According to http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/c6e6b26c-be52-4176-b1e5-bb628d10acd0.htm  (using the C# example at the bottom of the page)

I'm taking and IGeometry type (boundary) and casting that polygon's envelope to an IEnvelope (envelope) with which I am hoping to look at the width and height properties

But envelope is always null

```
    IGeometry boundary;

    var wktReader = new WKTReader(OSGBGeometryFactory.Factory);
    boundary = wktReader.Read(projectDTO.BoundaryWKT);

    IEnvelope envelope = boundary.Envelope as IEnvelope;
```

Can anyone help, this is my first time with this suite.

---

What I'm trying to work out is if following this example I already have an IGeometry type (my boundary variable)   why is it null when I try and cast it.

```
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;

class temp
{
  public void test()
  {
    // Create an empty polygon object.
    IArea areaPolygon = new PolygonClass();

    // Cast to the IGeometry interface of the polygon object.
    IGeometry geometryPolygon = (IGeometry)areaPolygon;

    // Use the .Envelope property on the IGeometry interface of the
    // polygon object to get an envelope object.
    IEnvelope envelope = geometryPolygon.Envelope;

    // Test to make sure you have an envelope object.
    if (envelope is Envelope)
    {
      // The polygon object and resulting envelope are empty.
      if (envelope.IsEmpty)
      {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("The envelope is empty.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Do I need to create a new polygon and try casting that (i.e., replicate the `IArea areaPolygon = new PolygonClass();`)?

Answer (score 4):

I too faced the same problem. It is an issue of the API developer using a weird naming convention for Envelope. `IGeometry.Envelope` is actually an IGeometry object. You should instead use `IGeometry.EnvelopeInternal` instead.

```
IGeometry boundary;

var wktReader = new WKTReader(OSGBGeometryFactory.Factory);
boundary = wktReader.Read(projectDTO.BoundaryWKT);

IEnvelope envelope = boundary.EnvelopeInternal;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what OSGBGeometryFactory.Factory does, as a reader ususally takes some WKT. Here is an example that does what you want, where the WKT was created by buffering a point in postgis, for what it is worth.

```
        WKTReader rdr = new WKTReader();
        Polygon poly =(Polygon) rdr.Read(
                "POLYGON((10 0,9.23879532511287 -3.82683432365089,7.07106781186548 -7.07106781186547,3.82683432365091 -9.23879532511286,1.61554255216634e-14 -10,-3.82683432365088 -9.23879532511287,-7.07106781186546 -7.07106781186549,-9.23879532511286 -3.82683432365092,-10 -3.23108510433268e-14,-9.23879532511288 3.82683432365086,-7.0710678118655 7.07106781186545,-3.82683432365094 9.23879532511285,-4.62458305157398e-14 10,3.82683432365085 9.23879532511289,7.07106781186544 7.07106781186551,9.23879532511284 3.82683432365095,10 0))");
        GeoAPI.Geometries.ICoordinate [] coords =  poly.Envelope.Coordinates;
        double width = coords[2].X - coords[0].X;
        double height = coords[2].Y - coords[0].Y;

        Console.WriteLine("width={0:f}, height={1:f}", width, height);
```